# Scheduling system for movie theatre / cinema - multiple showtimes

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently developing a web app with PHP and mysql that allows the admin to add movies and showtimes.

The cinema has 3 different theaters: Theatre 1, Theatre 2 and Theatre 3.

I'm having problems combing multiple showtimes.

This is my "table_showtimes".

```
movie    day_start     day_end        showtime    theatre
Hobbit   2014-01-01    2014-01-10     16.00       1
Hobbit   2014-01-08    2014-01-14     18.00       1
```

As you see, the movie "Hobbit" plays from Jan 01 until Jan 10 at 4pm in theatre 1
and from Jan 08 until Jan 14 also at 6pm in theatre 1.

Now, I would like to display the following front end view for the user, sorted chronologically:

```
HOBBIT
01/01 - 07/01    16.00            Theatre 1
08/01 - 10/01    16.00 + 18.00    Theatre 1
11/01 - 14/01    18.00            Theatre 1
```

I'm having difficulties displaying the combined showimtes (16.00 + 18.00).

Do you think I should loop through every day of a month and check for available showtimes or sort via SQL?

Thank you very much for your suggestions!
Matthias

Comment: Looping through each day is necessary. Especially when you factor in the possible complicated schedule, maybe the table structure should be changed too.  In your current structure, it would be difficult to enter schedules like movie A on every Mon/Wed/Fri and Movie B on Every Tue/Thr, or any of the temporarily no shows.

Answer (score 0):

It takes GROUP_CONCAT to put together your showtimes.

I set this up in a fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8e40/32/0

Basically you need to start with a way to enumerate all days, like so:

```
SELECT (day_start + INTERVAL numbers.number DAY) as DAY
  FROM (
       SELECT min(day_start) AS day_start,
              max(day_end) AS day_end
         FROM showtimes
         ) AS daterange
    JOIN (
     SELECT (u.number + 10*t.number + 100*h.number) AS number
       FROM number AS u
       JOIN number AS t
       JOIN number AS h
      ORDER BY number
     ) AS numbers
    WHERE numbers.number <= datediff(day_end, day_start)
```

Then you join that to your showtimes table like so, to get a resultset with a row for each day.

```
SELECT day, 
       movie,
       GROUP_CONCAT(date_format(showtime,'%H:%i')
                    ORDER BY showtime
                    SEPARATOR ' + ') AS showtimes,
       theatre
  FROM showtimes AS s
  JOIN (
      /* the query enumerating the days */          
      ) AS d 
  ON d.day BETWEEN s.day_start AND s.day_end
GROUP BY day,movie, theatre
```

See how the GROUP_CONCAT works in the context of the GROUP BY?

```
       GROUP_CONCAT(date_format(showtime,'%H:%i')
                    ORDER BY showtime
                    SEPARATOR ' + ') AS showtimes
```

Special note: I had to create a table numbers containing the integers from 0 to 9 to get the date enumeration to work.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is never necessary. IMO it's always preferable to manage any form of concatenation at the application level (e.g. a simple PHP loop)

Comment: What is "SEPARATOR" here ?

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT assembles a string from a sequence of strings, and SEPARATOR specifies what goes between the members of the sequence. If you don't give SEPARATOR, you get ", " (comma, space).

Comment: @Strawberry, SQL is never necessary. IMO it's possible to use MUMPS for all your data management needs. Oh, wait. SQL works better and nobody knows how to run MUMPS any more.  :-) :-) Seriously, aggregate functions are really useful. With respect, you may be doing a disservice to people who are just getting started with your absolutist advice against GROUP_CONCAT. There are many ways to get things done.

Comment: Aggregate functions are fantastic - just not that one.